# Re-sizing dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have written the following code to resize an array if the an item is going to go out of range when storing it. This code works as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//! Our location struct for storing locations
struct location
{
    char loc_name[35];
    char description[85];
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
};

void runMenu();
void add_location(struct location** p_location_array, int* p_array_size, int* p_current_size);
void resize_array(struct location** p_location_array, int* p_array_size);
void print (struct location* p_array, int p_current_size);

// Print out the main menu to the user.
void runMenu()
{
    printf("[A]dd additional Locations\n");
    printf("[P]rint the current list of locations\n");\
    printf("[Q]uit the program\n");
}

//! Resize the array to two times it's origional size.
void resize_array(struct location** p_location_array, int* p_array_size)
{
    // Allocate enough space for two times the size of the array
    int new_size = 2 * (*p_array_size);
    struct location* new_location_array = malloc(new_size * sizeof(struct location));
    if (!new_location_array)
    {
        printf ("Cannot add more elements heap has exhausted all space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Copy the old array to the new array.
    memcpy(new_location_array, *p_location_array, ((*p_array_size ) * sizeof(struct location)));
    // We will update the current size of the array for later checking.
    *p_array_size = 2 * (*p_array_size);
    // We have a copy of the old array so we can free it.
    free(*p_location_array);
    // The contents of the pointer reference get the array we malloced in this function
    *p_location_array = new_location_array;
}

//! Add a new location to our array. If the array isn't large enough resize it then insert the new struct.
void add_location(struct location** p_location_array, int* p_array_size, int* p_current_size )
{
    // Get the users input
    struct location new_location;
    printf("Enter the new location name\n ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", new_location.loc_name); 
    printf("Enter a description of the location\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", new_location.description),
    printf("Enter the latitude\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%f", &new_location.latitude);
    printf("Enter the longitude\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%f", &new_location.longitude);

    // Check to see if the size is correct.
    if (*p_array_size <= *p_current_size)
    {
        // If not the correct size resize the array
        resize_array(p_location_array, p_array_size);
    }
    // Insert our sruct
    (*p_location_array)[*p_current_size] = new_location;
}

//! Loop over and print out the locations
void print (struct location* p_array, int p_current_size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < p_current_size; i++)
    {
        struct location current = p_array[i];
        printf("%s :  %s  : %f : %f\n", current.loc_name, current.description, current.latitude, current.longitude);
    } 
}



int main()
{
    char choice = ' ';
    short control = 1;
    int size;
    int currentSize = 0;

    printf("Enter the inital size of the array\n");
    scanf(" %d", &size);

    // Make a new struct array from the heap
    struct location* m_location_array = 
         malloc(size * sizeof(struct location));

    // Make sure we have a valid chunk of the heap.
    if (!m_location_array)
        exit(1);

    while(control)
    {
        runMenu();
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                // Do Add additional
                add_location(&m_location_array, &size, &currentSize);
                currentSize++;
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
                // Do printing
                print (m_location_array, currentSize);
                break;
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
                control = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input\n");
        }   
    }
    // clean up after ourselves.
    free (m_location_array);
    return 0;

}
```

However, when I originally wrote this function I thought it would be possible to just pass in a the pointer to the array instead of a reference to the pointer like so:

```
 void resize_array(struct location* p_location_array, int* p_array_size)
```

Calling this function without the reference to pointer threw a segfault indicating the memory was being doubly freed. Is that because the pointer when passed to the function someway gets freed and reallocated? Furthermore, why is it necessary to pass a pointer by reference like this? Even if the pointer is a copy of the original pointer wouldn't it still point to the same piece of memory? Any points in the correct direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs I have this was actually an assignment for a class and realloc was off limits. I just want to understand why my intuition in this case was incorrect.

Comment: In C, everything is passed by value.  to change where a variable in a callers' function points, the address of the variable must be passed, not the contents. of the pointer.   That is why the `**` is used and when calling the sub function, the `&` must be used on the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave a pointer to the function and you have a call to `free` there. So the memory is freed. After that using that pointer causes undefined behaviour and you may not use it.

Modifying the pointer variable inside the function doesn't change the pointer outside the function. That is why you need a pointer to the pointer so that you can modify the pointer variable outside the function.

> Even if the pointer is a copy of the original pointer wouldn't it still point to the same piece of memory?

Yes, and that is the point: it will keep on pointing to the same place unless you change it. If you do a new `malloc` it will point to a completely different place.

Also a hint: `realloc` might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass pointer to function it is a copy of original one. Then even if you assign to this pointer inside the function, like

```
p_location_array = new_location_array;
```

the original pointer (that outside the function) still has unchanged value.  So in case the original pointer pointed to some memory area and you have passed it to the function

```
void resize_array(struct location *p_location_array, int* p_array_size)
```

and you have called `free()` inside thefunction and assigned `NULL` to the pointer, after your function has returned the original pointer will comapre as not `NULL`.

```
// warning, changed prototype
void resize_array(struct location *p_location_array, int* p_array_size);

struct location *loc = malloc(size * sizeof(struct location)); // assume loc = 0x12345678
if (loc == NULL) EXIT_FAILURE;
// change pointer inside the function
// assign NULL to the pointer
resize_array(loc, size_p);
if (loc != NULL)
    free(loc);  // this will be called, loc is still 0x12345678,
                // double free, UB
```